# Adding text to the end of a search

Tags: regex

I am trying to add the the word surrounded by parenthesis (Preferred) to the end of my `findstr` search. The command I am using is

```
`ipconfig | findstr /R [0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*(Preferred) >> results.txt`.
```

The text file is not showing any found results in the file. I have been searching for four hours trying to figure it out. I have found that by removing `(Preferred)` I get the IP addresses but i need the "(Preferred)" text added to the end. Example of what I am looking for in the text file is, `IPv4 ..... xxx.xxx.xxx.x(Preferred)`. Could someone please help.

Comment: try `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\(Preferred\)`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it did not get me what I was looking for. I think that is adding an additional parameter to the findstr and yielding no results as IP addresses do not contain "(Preferred)".

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you

```
[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9](?:\(Preferred\))
```

Here is an online demo:

http://regex101.com/r/lL1bY1